# Security Rule "hasChild() || true" resolving to false?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

For some reason the following security rule is resolving to `false` when I try to write an object without the property that should be verified in `.hasChild(newData.child('ownerId').val())`. The property isn't mandatory, so I'm up to accept a write without it.

```
"pizza": {
   "$pizzaId": {
       ".write": "root.child('users').hasChild(newData.child('ownerId').val()) || true"
   }
}
```

Thus, I'm getting a `PERMISSION_DENIED` when running something like the code bellow:

```
firebase.database().ref(`pizza/peperoneID`).set({
  extraPepe: true
});
```

I know that I can fix it by just going with `(newData.child('ownerId').exists() && .hasChild(...)) || true` but I'm really trying to understand why the first option isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `ownerId`, you'll be passing `null` when you call `hasChild`.

That'll effect an error and that error will see your rule fail - so the trailing `|| true` is ineffectual.

Comment: Thanks for the reply cartant! I was supposing so but why couldnt we have the `hasChild()` returning `false` in this situation? At least a better error message instead of just saying that my `".write"` statement returned false. :/ Fireabase sec rules isnt the most trivial stuff and the logic tends to get huge when adding complexity to the application... and having to deal with this prechecks just makes it worst.

Comment: Because that's just how it happens to be implemented. Because [`hasChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#haschildchildpath) takes a string and you're passing a `null`. Because denying access if an error is effected makes more sense than granting access. Because it's better to present a non-specific error message to the client. And because you're supposed to test your rules - as you've done, or are doing.